# Is it possible to create a functionality about user registration with Pudit or Devise on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, pundit

I already used Pudit and Devise for registration and authorization via the web interface.

But I want to support via REST interface too. Is it possible to use Pudit or Devise for doing that. For example, sending this JSON for creating a new user

```
{
    "email":"user@mail.com",
    "password":"password",
     "confirm_password":"password"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is possible. I have used Devise gem to create user registration with RESTful api. RESTful api like - http://APPLICATION_URL/api/v1/users/sign_up.json
and You can post json parameter as follows
{"user": {"email":"user@mail.com","password":"password",
"confirm_password":"password"} }

Thanks,
Kapil Chothe